# Convert string to date time and format to specific format in string

Tags: c#

the string is 20131024174621 which is year =2013, month=10, date=24, hours=17, minutes=46, seconds=21
What I am trying to do is to convert and format it into 2013-10-24 17:46:21.
I have tried my luck as the code below however it return such error :

> *String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.*

```
String timestamp = "20131024174621";
String converted = DateTime.Parse(timestamp).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

What should be the way of doing it right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use `ParseExact`.

```
void Main()
{
    String timestamp = "20131024174621";
    var date = DateTime.ParseExact(timestamp, "yyyyMMddHHmmss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    Console.WriteLine (date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
}
```

Output:

> 2013-10-24 17:46:21

Answer (score 3):

```
DateTime.ParseExact( timestamp, "yyyyMMddHHmmss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture ).ToString( "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" );
```

Comment: I would encourage you to explicitly specify the invariant culture on both of those calls as well, otherwise it will behave differently in cultures which use a different calendar.

Comment: Thanks, I'm quite aware about the invariant culture and always use it.  I just thought it made not much sense when there were only digits in the string (no culture-specific separators and no month names). However I've just rechecked MSDN and now am totally agree with you - it's recommended to use the invariant culture in the very this case.

Comment: Thanks! I never aware about the invariant culture before this!

Comment: @JustAndrei: The important bit is that it determines the calendar as well. So a particular combination of year/month/day may be valid in one calendar but not another. I which ParseExact used the invariant culture by default, personally...

Answer (score 1):

Since other two answer is correct, I want to point the root of your problem.

[`DateTime.Parse` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ey1cdcx8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) uses [`Standard Date and Time Format Strings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). From [`How Standard Format Strings Work`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> In a formatting operation, a standard format string is simply an alias
>   for a custom format string. The advantage of using an alias to refer
>   to a custom format string is that, although the alias remains
>   invariant, the custom format string itself can vary. This is important
>   because the string representations of date and time values typically
>   vary by culture. For example, the "d" standard format string indicates
>   that a date and time value is to be displayed using a short date
>   pattern. For the `invariant culture`, this pattern is `"MM/dd/yyyy"`. For
>   the `fr-FR` culture, it is `"dd/MM/yyyy"`. For the `ja-JP` culture, it is
>   `"yyyy/MM/dd"`

In `20131024174621` string, you need `yyyyMMddHHmmss` format for your current culture. Looks like your culture doesn't have this format and that's why you get this error.

For this kind of non-standart format string, you can use [`custom date format`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx).

> Any string that is not a standard date and time format string is
>   interpreted as a custom date and time format string.

As I wrote in third paragraph, this kind of date formats is based on culture. When you have this kind of custom date strings, in most case using [`DateTime.ParseExact Method (String, String, IFormatProvider)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with specific culture is the best choice.